# MySQL Regexp search keyword

Tags: mysql, regex

I use this query

```
SELECT keyword
FROM files
UNION SELECT keyword
FROM search
WHERE keyword
REGEXP "/(honda)|(jazz)|(manual)/"
AND keyword !=  "honda jazz manual"
ORDER BY keyword ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

but I got this result

> Big bang theory reference

I want to asking you guys, how to use regexp to search keyword.

Comment: you need to include schema for files and search

Comment: the 'where' clause won't be applied to the first select in the union.. so, if _'Big bang theory reference'_ is in your _files_ table it will always be returned.

Comment: This doesn't fix your issue, but remove the forward slashes from your regular expression.  They are treated as literals by MySQL.

Comment: `"(honda)|(jazz)|(manual)"` still got same result, `big bang` included.

Comment: "This doesn't fix your issue..."

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
SELECT keyword
FROM
(SELECT keyword
 FROM files
 UNION SELECT keyword
 FROM search) allkeywords
WHERE keyword REGEXP '(honda|jazz|manual)'
AND keyword !=  'honda jazz manual'
ORDER BY keyword ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9341ff/5

Explanation:

(1) The unioned query needed making into a subquery to allow the WHERE clause to affect all of it.

(2) The REGEXP syntax was slightly wrong - parentheses round the whole OR'd expression, not individual items.